# How to get public key and bitcoin compressed address from the coordinates (x,y) generated by ECDSA?

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa, cryptocurrency

I have my x (0xca668a8b5f71e8724aada4b5343c28702a481787855cc42228b8fff97fe94d6a)  and y (0x19dd3a603a55b3d8c5f62cbe177b9b63693fb8c91d76845bafc843a7aa19ea55) coordinates generated by ecdsa with a private key. But don't know yet how to get the public address from (x,y) coordinates and a compressed bitcoin address ?

Comment: Edited #kelalaka

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/66157/108963

Comment: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/58114/108963

Comment: As you can see there are answers on Bitcoin.SE. If those answers satisfies you, you can delete this. If not search there more. I don't think that this is suitable here.

Comment: https://github.com/libbitcoin/libbitcoin-explorer https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/44283/correct-way-to-convert-a-256-bit-private-key-to-wif?rq=1